# Does a published artifact affect npm install?

Tags: npm

I have a private, unpublished NPM package. Let's say it's named `foo-test`:

```json
{
  "name": "foo-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {...},
  "dependencies": {...}
}
```

It's not in the NPM registry, and I've marked it [private](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#private).

I found out via a security audit that this is *"vulnerable to dependency confusion attacks"*, but I don't know how.

If someone later comes along and publishes a *real* public package called `foo-test` to the NPM registry, will that affect my local development against my private package?

That is, let's say there's a real package `foo-test@1.0.0` available on npmjs. If I run `npm install` locally against my own unrelated version of `foo-test`, will there be any side effects arising from the fact that the local package that I'm building has the same name as a public package on the registry?

Comment: Do you mean when you install the dependencies of `foo-test` itself, or when you install that package in systems that utilise it (_are_ there any such systems)?

Comment: This should be a helpful explanation on mitigation: https://github.blog/2021-02-12-avoiding-npm-substitution-attacks/, along with this [article](https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610) on an example dependency confusion attack using npm.

Comment: It was reported that when you run `npm i` on _this_ private package, it is vulnerable because of the (potential) collision with the published artifact @jonrsharpe. And no there are no systems that depend on this package, it's a standalone application

Comment: Reported by what (or whom)? Do you have any similar packages in `foo-test`'s dependencies? `npm i` is just going to use the `package{,-lock}.json` to determine which dependencies `foo-test` needs, it's not going to pull down some existing `foo-test` from the registry (and if you try to `npm i foo-test` within `foo-test` you'll get `ENOSELF`).

Comment: Reported by a "security researcher" (chasing a bug bounty.) I'm just trying to figure out if they're blowing smoke because my understanding of `npm i` is that it's just going to resolve the listed dependencies with regard to the lock.

Comment: So ask _them_ for clarity on how exactly they think it can be exploited. _Consumers_ of your package might get confused, but you say you don't have any.

Comment: They "proved" the exploit by publishing a "foo-test" library into npmjs so we now do have the collision. I don't have direct contact with them, I'm just the end-of-the-line person who has to either fix it or explain how it's not legit. So I'm asking here: if I have a private local package with a name that collides with a public published package, will the published package in anyway affect my local package when I do an npm i.

Comment: But that's only a collisions for _consumers_ of foo-test. As you can demonstrate for yourself, running `npm i` in foo-test itself still works fine (and you can use `--verbose` to see it doesn't make a request relating to that published package when doing so).